# Remove all markers without the use of map.clear() Google maps - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin

I am attempting to have a GPS location system that will update the users position every second, continuously draw the route they have traveled with Poly-lines, and move the marker to their newest position on every change.

Is there a nice way in Xamarin to remove all markers, but *without* clearing the previously attached polyline (like `map.clear()` would)

Now I understand that I could store the co-ordinates locally and then re-draw them each time, however this could end up being a *very* long route, and I would rather not have to do this, as eventually there will be a hard limit, where it cannot draw the full route, before the next set of co-ordinates come through and would prefer just to append the newest line to the previously drawn lines, and just move the marker.

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you just keep a hold of the last marker then clear that one when you get a new one. the marker object has a `remove` method, well at least in java it does

Comment: Aye I did find that, but I don't have it in Xamarin, theres a .dispose(), but it doesn't appear to do anything..

Comment: just another reason for me to never use cross platform development like Xamarin

Comment: I'm glad I could help you come to that conclusion

Comment: And that one is not a correct one. Even on Xamarin.Android you have a Remove method on the marker object, but you should just know your tools.

Comment: All documentation says to use the MarkerOptions object, which does not have a remove method.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#public-constructor-summary

Comment: The `Marker` object that that returned from `AddMarker` has a `.Remove` method, I would assume you are not casting it if you do not "see" the method in Intellisense.

Comment: @SushiHangover by casting it, I have got it working now. Thank you very much, if you would post this as an answer I will happily accept.

Comment: @Aphire glad to help. When you see that the returned object from an Android/Java-based API is a plain/generic Java object, casting it before you save it to a local var (or later) will be required to access its props/methods... lots of the Java APIs return plain old base objects so just check the Google's doc on the API to double check what they are actually returning and go from there.

Comment: That's great, thanks very much for the concise, polite explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Marker` object that that returned from the map `AddMarker` method has a `.Remove` method.

Casting this returned object as a `Maker` will allow you access to the `.Remove` method to delete it from the map that it is currently attached to.

Most developers store these returned masker objects in a dictionary/list/... You can either save them as the generic java object that is returned or create a Maker-based generic collection so casting later is not required.

Answer (score 0):

To remove markers without clearing the map through the Clear method you need to keep track of all your markers.

```
var marker = Map.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(MyPosition.Latitude, MyPosition.Longitude)));

markerList.Add(marker);
```

Each marker has a Remove method you can than call by iterating through the markerList.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it, Sushi's comment did in fact lead me to solve the issue, if he does not post an answer anytime soon, I will accept this as the answer instead